# Python3 Pandas column in seconds

Tags: python, datetime, csv, python-3.x, pandas

I have this .csv file containing data looking like this

```
"Time","CH-1[V]","CH-2[V]","CH-3[V]",
 0.000000000E+00,-4.07000E-01, 3.01000E-01,-4.40000E-01,
 1.000000000E+01,-4.11000E-01, 3.01000E-01,-4.29000E-01,
 2.000000000E+01,-3.99000E-01, 3.01000E-01,-4.15000E-01,
 3.000000000E+01,-3.87000E-01, 3.01000E-01,-4.09000E-01,
 4.000000000E+01,-3.79000E-01, 3.00000E-01,-4.15000E-01,
```

The "Time" column is in seconds. The file also contains a Trigger Time formatted as `14-10-25 16:07:40` which is the starting point for Time.

I want to change the first column to be `Time*TriggerTime`.

All I got so far is a function to convert triggertime to datetime and

```
parse = lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%S')
content2 = pd.read_csv(current_file, parse_dates=['Time'], index_col=0, date_parser=parse)
```

but I seem to get an error:

```
ValueError: time data ' 0.000000000E+00' does not match format '%S'
```

which I can't solve.

Any help ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [9]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=0)

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
      CH-1[V]  CH-2[V]  CH-3[V]  Unnamed: 4
Time
0      -0.407    0.301   -0.440         NaN
10     -0.411    0.301   -0.429         NaN
20     -0.399    0.301   -0.415         NaN
30     -0.387    0.301   -0.409         NaN
40     -0.379    0.300   -0.415         NaN
```

Convert the column that is in seconds to a Timedelta, then add it to a Timestamp

```
In [13]: pd.to_timedelta(df.index,unit='s') + pd.Timestamp('20141015 16:07:40')
Out[13]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-10-15 16:07:40, ..., 2014-10-15 16:08:20]
Length: 5, Freq: None, Timezone: None


In [14]: (pd.to_timedelta(df.index,unit='s') + pd.Timestamp('20141015 16:07:40')).tolist()
Out[14]:
[Timestamp('2014-10-15 16:07:40'),
 Timestamp('2014-10-15 16:07:50'),
 Timestamp('2014-10-15 16:08:00'),
 Timestamp('2014-10-15 16:08:10'),
 Timestamp('2014-10-15 16:08:20')]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I just cant seem to get it working, keep getting an error
ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'numpy.float64'>

Comment: you need 0.15.2 (alternatively, if you only have 0.15.0, you as do ``pd.Int64Index(df.index)``) in place of df.index